# is shorthand if statment refactoring possible?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a way to make a shorthand for an [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)?

for

```
if(window.scrollY > 0 ){
        alert("yes")
}
```

This shorthand will not work

```
 window.scrollY > 0 ? alert("yes")
```

while this will work fine

```
window.scrollY > 0 ?  alert("yes") : alert("no")
```

is there a way to write the shorthand without the `: alert("no")` part?

Comment: No. A ternary operator must have an else. Otherwise it's a syntax error. `if(window.scrollY > 0 ) alert("yes");` is probably the shortest you're going to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put `null` for the unwanted case:

```
window.scrollY > 0 ? alert("yes") : null;
```

Or, as @hsz points out, you can take advantage of the short-circuiting nature of JavaScript's boolean expressions and use:

```
window.scrollY > 0 && alert("Yes");
// or even take advantage of the fact that zero coerces to false
window.scrollY && alert("Yes");
```

However, these are not as readable (to my mind) as simply using the one-line (braceless) `if`:

```
if(window.scrollY > 0) alert("yes");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try with:

```
 window.scrollY > 0 && alert("yes");
```

Comment: Oh man, I've seen people do this and every time I cringe. I know, it's fine, but it just looks so horrid to me.

Comment: @RGraham I don't use this statement because its not so readable - but it's works and it is the shortest form. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the `alert("no")` with `0`, since ternary operators *always* have to have a "false" parameter:

```js
prompt('value') > 0 ? alert("yes") : 0 ;
```

However, this is a little ugly.

A better option is to only execute a function if a statement is true:

```js
prompt('value') > 0 && alert("yes");
```

The `&&` will only evaluate the right side of the expression, if the left side is truthy.

<sub>(Try entering `1` and `0` in the prompts)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
window.scrollY > 0 ? alert("yes") : alert("no");
```

is called a `ternary operator`. It is usually used to determine a return value from a statement.

You can achieve what you mean in such a way:

```
(window.scrollY > 0) && alert("yes");
```

Anyway, in no way is it better than plain `if/else`. It isn't more readable.